# Is it ok for a function or method not to be covered by a unit test? What situations?

Tags: unit-testing

Are there any situations where a function or method doesn't need to be covered by a unit test?  What situations would they be or do they not exist?

For example I have the following function.  It makes one call to another function, 'formatName' which is 100% covered by unit tests.

```
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    self.formattedName = ko.computed(function () {
        return AH.Helpers.formatName(self.name);
    });
}
```

Is the above function a bit redundant because all it does is call another method but then again I want to keep as much of the logic in my viewmodel.

If I do need a test for the above is it ok to just check formatName has been called using a spy

```
ok(AH.Helpers.formatName.calledOnce);
```

Should getters be covered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, it’s always OK for some code not to be covered by tests. Tests have a point of diminishing returns – a point where increasing coverage takes a lot of effort and doesn’t bring much value.

In your specific case, I think it makes sense to cover the call. But certainly not by checking if the helper was called, that’s knowing too much about the implementation. Creating a seat reservation should have an observable effect on the state of the object, like changing the formatted name. So I would test the method by passing some simple name to it and checking that the name was correctly formatted and `self.formattedName` updated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Zoul, I think that makes sense but...I feel that logic is already being covered by the formattedName tests.  What has actually happened is I've got a scenario similar to the above in my real world code and I seem to be retesting formattedName over and over which feels really redundant

Comment: @atreeonhill: you probably are testing your `toString` methods or casting operators a thousand times as well. I wouldn't worry about it, not as much as I'd worry about writing tests that are heavily dependent on implementation. If you change your implementation you will have an *enormous* number of **false positives**, which will help actual errors go unnoticed.

Comment: In general, be *especially* wary of false positives.

Comment: you've got me thinking, I guess the formattedName function on the viewmodel should check its interaction with the self.name property.  This is outside of the logic of formatName so its a good test.  Still feel there is quite a bit of duplication but I guess that bit of functionality should be tested.

Answer (score 1):

### My 2 cents: *yes*.

To compound [zoul's answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32451827/3881403) with whom I concur regarding your `formattedName` method: code coverage is not everything and [unit tests do *not*, in general, prove that a program is correct](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD03xx/EWD303.html), and this is to keep in mind when approaching them.

This is all the more true for simple line coverage - **even 100% line coverage does not mean *that* much** if you have a million different branches governed by complex rules.

As [one Mr. Bertrand Meyer aptly put it](http://se.ethz.ch/~meyer/publications/testing/principles.pdf) in his article, "Seven Principles of Software Testing",

> Testing a program to assess its quality is, in theory, **akin to 
>   sticking pins into a doll—very small pins, very large doll**.
>   [...]
>
> **To  test  a  program  is  to  try  to  make it fail**

Is **testing getters to death** - or any other simple method that can be verified by inspection - really **trying to make the program fail**?

In general, I would be wary of worshipping to the altar of metrics anyway.

Numbers must be always *interpreted*: in the extreme example, if you are king of a land in which a rich man eats two steaks a day and a poor man eats zero, it is of little value to say that your subjects eat a steak a day on average.

There is yet another interesting take from Alberto Savoia, "The Wisdom of Testivus" on [the Google Testing blog.](http://googletesting.blogspot.it/2010/07/code-coverage-goal-80-and-no-less.html)

> When I replied by asking her how many
>   grains of rice I should put in a pot, I helped her realize that the
>   amount of testing necessary depends on a number of factors, and she
>   knows those factors better than I do – it’s her code after all. There
>   is no single, simple, answer, and she’s smart enough to handle the
>   truth and work with that.”

This is not to be an invitation to sloppy testing or, worse, **ignoring methods that "are so simple" that "cannot possibly contain any errors".**

It's an invitation to **effective** testing, the kind of testing that gives you 90% chance of shipping bug free code with 20% of the effort instead of the other way around.

Comment: I'm trying not to become the third programmer!  Thanks